# Reference .json file for external dataset in ng2-nvd3

Tags: json, d3.js, angular, ng2-nvd3

I'm using ng2-nvd3, and I want to access external json data. Based on the below code snippet, how do I reference the .json file that would hold the same data as displayed in the this.data array below?

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
declare let d3:any;
import {nvD3} from 'ng2-nvd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'bar-chart',
  directives: [nvD3],
  template: `
    <div>
      <nvd3 [options]="options" [data]="data"></nvd3>
    </div>
  `
})
export class BarChartComponent {
  options;
  data;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'discreteBarChart',
        height: 450,
        margin: {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 50,
          left: 55
        },
        x: function (d) {
          return d.label;
        },
        y: function (d) {
          return d.value;
        },
        showValues: true,
        valueFormat: function(d){
          return d3.format(',.4f')(d);
        },
        duration: 500,
        xAxis: {
          axisLabel: 'X axis',
        },
        yAxis: {
          axisLabel: 'Y axis',
          axisLabelDistance: -10
        }
      }
    }

    //Want to replace this with an external json file.
    this.data = [
      {
        key: "Cumulative Return",
        values: [
          {
            "label": "A",
            "value": -29.765957771107
          },
          {
            "label": "B",
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "label": "C",
            "value": 32.807804682612
          },
          {
            "label": "D",
            "value": 196.45946739256
          },
          {
            "label": "E",
            "value": 0.19434030906893
          },
          {
            "label": "F",
            "value": -98.079782601442
          },
          {
            "label": "G",
            "value": -13.925743130903
          },
          {
            "label": "H",
            "value": -5.1387322875705
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to load the file at runtime with HTTP, or is it always static and you just want to move it to another file to keep this component small?

Comment: @James Stewart, how can one handle the load file at runtime with http. That is what I want .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the data to be in a separate file.

create a new file:

> your.data.service.ts

in there:

```
export class YourDataService{


   public data: Array<any> = [
     {
       key: "Cumulative Return",
       values: [
         {
           "label": "A",
           "value": -29.765957771107
         }]
   }]
```

then import it in the component and reference it

```
import{YourDataService} from './your.data.service.ts'


public _data: Array<any>= YourDataService.data;
```

Comment: please can you help answer this question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709470/how-to-use-dynamic-csv-data-for-visualisation-with-nvd3-and-angular2