# How to use dynamic CSV data for visualisation with nvd3 and angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to load a CSV data and plot graphs based on the returned data.I could see the data when logged to the console, but it does not get plotted in the graph. When I replaced the data copied from the console with the function written to return the data, the graph get plotted. I dont know what I am missing.

my code looks like this

```
  // Options and Data definitions

   declare let d3, nv: any;

  export const ChartTypes = [
      'lineChart',
      'discreteBarChart'

        ];

   const color = d3.scale.category20()

    export const AllOptions = {

             discreteBarChart: {
                           chart: {
                            type: 'discreteBarChart',
                            height: 450,
                            margin : {
                                 top: 20,
                                 right: 20,
                                 bottom: 50,
                                 left: 55
                                     },
                            x: function(d){return d.label;},
                            y: function(d){return d.value;},
                           showValues: true,
                         valueFormat: function(d){
                          return d3.format(',.4f')(d);
                            },
                          duration: 500,
                          xAxis: {
                          axisLabel: 'X Axis'
                                   },
                       yAxis: {
                      axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                      axisLabelDistance: -10
                               }
                              }
                       }
                }
```

Getting data into the object

```
export const AllData = {
// populate the empty object with your data

      discreteBarChart: getCsvData()
   }
```

The getCsvData() function that gets the data from the csv looks like this:

```
          function getCsvData(){


               d3.csv("app/test.csv", function(error, data){
              var dynamicData = data;
              console.log(data)
             // create an empty object that nv is expecting
             var discreteBarChart = [
                {
                   key: "Cumulative Return",
                  values: []
                }
      ];
           data.forEach(function (d){
           d.value = +d.value
           discreteBarChart[0].values.push(d)
      })



console.log('The data is'+JSON.stringify(discreteBarChart))
    })

      return discreteBarChart

      }
```

I got undefined when I attempted to do an alert of the function like this

```
   alert(JSON.stringify(getCsvData()))
```

I suspect the problem is, I put the returned statement in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use the asynchronous `d3.csv()` function in a synchronous way. When you call `return discreteBarChart` it immediately returns `undefined` without waiting for you data request to finish. By the time your data comes back, you aren't passing it anywhere.

You either need to make your `getCsvData()` function accept a callback for it to call when the data loads, or use JavaScript Promises, which I think would be a better solution.

Using promises, your code could look something like this:

```
function getCsvData() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    d3.csv("app/test.csv", function(error, data) {
      var discreteBarChart = [{
        key: "Cumulative Return",
        values: []
      }];
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.value = +d.value
        discreteBarChart[0].values.push(d)
      });
      resolve(discreteBarChart);
    });
  });
}

getCsvData().then(function(data) {
  // Use the data here to render your chart
});
```